# Tracking the intersection of a vertical line and a continuously changing sinusoid that is contracting while propagating and also varying its amplitude

Tags: trigonometry

With what equation can one model the sinusoid over time in the $xy$-plane?

The best I've been able to do is consider a special case. This is what I have so far:

Consider a sinusoid with some amplitude and some wavelength which is propagating in a straight line path with some propagation speed that may vary over time. Imagine that the sinusoid is continuously stretching and compressing over time such that the wavelength and amplitude both change over time.

Define:

$$a=f\left(t,\alpha\right)$$

$$b=g\left(t,\beta\right)$$

$$c=h\left(t,k\right)$$

For the sake of illustrating an example I've chosen to consider a particular predefined way in which the sinusoid's shape and position change over time $f\left(t,\alpha\right)={\alpha}t+\frac{1}{10\alpha}$, $g\left(t,\beta\right)={\beta}t$ and $h\left(t,k\right)={k}t$. I set some arbitrary values for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $k$

Then an equation to model our sinusoid is

$$S\left(t,x\right)=a\cos\left(bx+c\right)$$

The question then is what is the $y$ coordinate of the intersection of the graph of $y=S\left(t_{0},x\right)$ with the vertical line $x=x_0$

Additionally, how does this intersection point vary as you increase the value of $t$

The $y$ coordinate of this intersection point is $a\cos\left(bx_{0}+c\right)$

I'll refer to this $y$ coordinate as $H$ where $H$ is the height of the intersection above the $x$ axis. That is, if $H$ is negative then the intersection occurs below the $x$ axis

We can see that $H$ is a single-variable function of the time $t$

A next natural question is what is the derivative of $H$ with respect to the time variable $t$:

$$\frac{dH}{dt}=a\cos\left(bx_{0}+kt\right)-\left(\alpha t+\frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\left(\beta x_{0}+k\right)\sin\left(bx_{0}+c\right)$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vumft0ndh6) I've made a graph modeling the changing sinusoid with this particular choice of $f$, $g$ and $h$.

Another question to ask is: what is the $x$-coordinate of the fixed point? The points on the sinusoid get shifted over to different locations as the sinusoid transformation takes place. There is a unique point along the sinusoid whose location remains constant throughout the transformation (as $t$ varies). I believe that in order to derive the answer to this question you must deal with an elliptic integral of the second kind which comes about from the calculation of the arc length of the sinusoid. However, I am not sure if there are easier ways of coming up with the answer to this question.

Comment: You have $t$ in too many places. You can get away with this in Desmos because it is treated as a local variable in most of the places you used it, but the transcription to this question loses that locality (and it was a bad idea anyway).

Comment: @DavidK I think I fixed it. Removed the parameter

Comment: You could also consistently use $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$ on the definitions of $f$, $g$, and $h.$ Also, since you really want $a,b,c$ to vary with $T$, they should be defined as functions of $T$ (and other parameters if you want). This is another place where something works in Desmos but is unclear in written math.

Comment: @DavidK you have a point there but I guess I wanted to set myself up such that if I want to I can go rewrite my $f$, $g$ and $h$ functions. Would it be more clear if I edit the post such that $f(t)$ becomes $f(t,T)$, or would that not necessarily help in making it clearer?

Comment: Yes, you can let $f$ be a function of $T$ and also a function of something else. That’s what I meant by “and other parameters”. I still think the multiple usage of the letter $t$ is confusing. Why not $f(\alpha,T)$?

Comment: OK, +1 for being so ready to improve the question. I’m not in a place where I can easily work on it at the moment but it is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Desmos simulation is quite entertaining. It looks like a spring being alternately compressed and stretched at both ends.

### More concise definition of $S(t,x)$

I'll start by eliminating the parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$ from the formula for $S(t,x)$ by substituting the functions to which those parameters have been equated:

$$ S(t,x) = f(t,\alpha) \cos\left(g(t,\beta)x+h(t,k)\right)$$

Now we can see exactly how $S$ is determined by just the two variables $t$ and $x$ and the parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$ (which we can consider as constants).

If we choose to fix a particular time $t$, say $t = t_0$, and then look at $S$ as merely a function of $x$, we have $S(t_0,x) = a \cos\left(bx+c\right)$, but with constant values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ (as long as we hold $t$ fixed to the same value), so this confirms that at any instant $t$ the graph of this formula over $x$ is a sinusoid. But you already knew that.

### General forms of $H(t)$ and its derivative

If instead we fix the value of $x$, say $x = x_0$, we have a function of $t$,

$$ H(t) =  f(t,\alpha) \cos\left(g(t,\beta) x_0 + h(t,k)\right). $$

In order to write some of the formulas more concisely,
let $\phi(t) = g(t,\beta) x_0 + h(t,k)$.
Then $H(t) = f(t,\alpha) \cos\left(\phi(t)\right)$ and

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} H(t)
&= \cos\left(\phi(t)\right) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(t,\alpha) 
+ f(t,\alpha) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\cos\left(\phi(t)\right)\\
&= \cos\left(\phi(t)\right) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(t,\alpha) 
- f(t,\alpha) \sin\left(\phi(t)\right) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\phi(t)\\
&= \cos\left(\phi(t)\right) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(t,\alpha) 
- f(t,\alpha) \sin\left(\phi(t)\right) 
  \left(x_0 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} g(t,\beta)
   + \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} h(t,k) \right).
\end{align}

### Specific example of $S(t,x)$

Now let's look at the particular set of functions used in the question,

\begin{align}
f(t, \alpha) &= \alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}, \\
g(t, \beta) &= \beta t, \\
h(t, k) &= kt.
\end{align}

Making these substitutions in the formula for $S(t,x)$, we have

$$
 S(t,x) = \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\cos\left(\beta tx + kt\right)
 = \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\cos\left((\beta x + k)t\right).
$$

### The fixed point

Note that when $x = -\dfrac k\beta$, then $\beta x + k = 0$ and therefore
$\cos\left((\beta x + k)t\right) = 1$ for all values of $t$.
This is your "fixed point".
It's not actually fixed in the plane because the $y$ value varies with
$f(t, \alpha)$, but it is a constant $x$ value that will always be exactly at one of the local maxima of the sinusoid.

### $H(t)$ and $H'(t)$ in the example

Continuing with the same definitions of $f$, $g$, and $h$, we get $H(t)$
from $S(t,x)$ by substituting $x_0$ for $x$:

$$
 H(t) = \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\cos\left((\beta x_0 + k)t\right)
= \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\cos(\omega t),
$$

where $\omega = \beta x_0 + k$ is now a fixed value.
Then

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} H(t)
&= \cos(\omega t)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right) 
+ \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\cos(\omega t)\\
&= \alpha\cos(\omega t) 
- \left(\alpha t + \frac{1}{10\alpha}\right) \omega\sin(\omega t).
\end{align}